# Coloring Entire Row doesn't work with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to color the whole rows based on values from the row, but nothing happens.

Column `AA` are filled with values from `ColorIndex`.

```
 Sub color()

  Dim color As Integer

  For Each cell In Sheets(1).Range("AA2:AA7000")

    If cell.Value = 6 Then
    ColorIndex = 6

        ElseIf cell.Value <> 6 Then ColorIndex = -4142

    End If

    cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = color

nextcell:

  Next cell

End Sub
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: As a general rule, you should avoid using `GoTo` statements. It is considered bad practice and can create messy code that acts unpredictably. Consider using better structured `If` statements instead.

Comment: You can step through your code using F8 and set breakpoints using F9 and follow the logic, check variables as you go. This will become crucial for you to learn how to debug your own logic.

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing as you have named it `color` and you are using `color` as a variable, and you never give that variable any value, so it defaults to `0`, so you are only setting `ColorIndex` to `0`.

Comment: I tried to remove all the codes relevant to `GoTo`, but the rows are still blank. Any solutions?

Comment: Try the solution that Storax posted. And try to learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you would like to do something like that

```
Sub color()

    Dim color As Long
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Sheets(1).Range("AA2:AA7000")

        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then

            If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then

                If cell.Value = 6 Then
                    color = 6
                ElseIf cell.Value < 35 Then
                    color = -4142
                Else
                    color = cell.Value
                End If
                cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = color

            End If
        End If

    Next cell

End Sub
```